# HTML markup manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

Working with PHP DOM - html manipulation. It's really very effective way to output HTML markup (at least, prevents mess of logic and markup in code).

But, to generate 50 line of html markup, one must write about 200 lines in PHP :( .

Example piece of code:

...

```
$signup_form = $document->createElement('form');
$signup_form->setAttribute('id', 'signup_form');
$signup_form->setAttribute('action', 'registration/signup.php');
$signup_form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
$su_fname_label = $document->createElement('label');
$su_fname_label->setAttribute('for', 'fname');
$su_fname_label_content = $document->createTextNode('Name');
$su_fname_label->appendChild($su_fname_label_content);
$su_fname_textbox = $document->createElement('input');
$su_fname_textbox->setAttribute('name', 'fname');
$su_fname_textbox->setAttribute('class', 'valid');
$su_fname_textbox->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Please enter your name');
$su_fname_textbox->setAttribute('type', 'text');
```

...

As you see, It's only 1 element of form. Imagine, If there are 5 elements in HTML form, php code will be huge. I wonder, is there any way to minify for ex. by setting multiple attributes at once? Any suggestions?

Comment: Whats the problem in embedding snippets of PHP in your HTML-code? I assume it will be MUCH more readable afterwards.

Comment: Wow, that's a funny one!

Comment: apart from writing your own helper functions or dedicated classes for creating individual elements, no. DOM is a verbose API.

Comment: It's a drawback indeed. However, I tend to not 'make' HTML this way: I just load in a pre-made HTML template, and fill in some details with PHP after that. I actually rather like the non-DOM-compliant `DOMDocumentFragment` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just output HTML and enabled output buffering. Then you can filter out the output using the `tidy` extension and be sure that your output HTML is valid, while still going as fast as writing pure HTML.

Despite the above, as @Gordon suggests:

> tidy is hardly suitable for programmatically authoring (x)html. its more like a post processor.

Comment: tidy has to be enabled iirc. dom is enabled by default. also, tidy is hardly suitable for programmatically authoring (x)html. its more like a post processor.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. Still, I find that in environments that HAVE tidy enabled, it's easier to use tidy.
Yes, it IS a post-processor. I am also suggesting it to be used like one.

Comment: Lol, well no skin off my back. I just contributed my answer, seems someone didn't like it :)

Answer (score 0):

What is your reason for using the DOM to generate html output? There's no way to make the DOM *terse*!

Usually you just use PHP for templating. Create a separate file like so:

```
<?php // template.php
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>',"\n";
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?=htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8')?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form id="signup_form" action="registration/signup.php" method="post">
           <label for="fname">Name</label>
           <input id="fname" name="fname" class="valid" placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text">
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then using a template function:

```
function render($__filename, $__data) {
    extract($__data, EXTR_SKIP);
    ob_start();
    include $__filename;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Render your template from your code like so:

```
do_something();
$templatedata = array('title'=>'The Title');
$html = render('template.php', $templatedata);
```

If you want something that is node-aware (which is a great idea for ensuring well-formedness and proper escaping!), you can use XSLT or a third-party template engine like [PHPTAL](http://phptal.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I used to do what you’re doing until I realized that it’s not very readable. You have to analyze the code to determine what markup is being built. It’s also harder to maintain. As you said, adding a single field to a form requires quite a bit of code and making changes requires digging through all that code. I agree with wanting to keep your PHP logic separate from your markup; however, there are better ways to keep your code clean depending on what you’re trying to do.

Without getting into third-party solutions you could:

1. [Load markup from a separate file into a DOM object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) for further manipulation.
2. Use PHP as the template engine it was designed to be by embedding PHP in your markup. As Col. Shrapnel explains quite eloquently: “[E]mbedded PHP lets you separate business logic from presentation logic on a site-wide basis, supporting templates of any size and structure…”.
3. Assign markup to a variable using [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). While not the best choice, it’s much easier to read than a purely DOM-based approach.

```
$signup_form = <<<EndHTMLForm
<form id="signup_form" action="registration/signup.php" method="post">
    <label for="fname">Name</label>
    <input name="fname" class="valid" placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text">
</form>
EndHTMLForm;
```

My purpose here isn’t to steer you *away* from third-party solutions, but to illustrate alternative approaches in plain-vanilla PHP. The DOM is verbose. It certainly has wonderful advantages, but creating markup from scratch isn’t one of them.

Comment: You are confused (2) and (3) descriptions. While embedded PHP lets you separate business logic from presentation logic on a site-wide basis, supporting templates of any size and structure, while heredoc is indeed for a "small doses", supports NO logic nor separation at all. Not to say that you are losing code highlighting with heredoc.

Comment: @Col: in (2) I was referring to "small doses" of PHP throughout an HTML template — as opposed to large sections of both, which I inferred that the OP was trying to avoid. I suppose I wasn't clear on that point, so I'll attempt to fix it. I absolutely agree, however, that any use of heredoc should be done in "small doses". Even without the benefit of code highlighting, my example is certainly more clear than the OP's DOM-based approach. These are presented only as possible alternatives since the OP never specified intention.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need for speed and if you're able to use caching and the like, a library such as [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) could be of use.

It's a "port" of kind of `jQuery` to PHP and has the same versatility and simplicity as `jQuery`. However, in my experience, it's not quite as fast as I should like in generating the code (I *have not*, however, conducted any thorough tests, it's just a feeling).

The code you've given as an example could be expressed along these lines with `phpQuery` (**untested**):

```
$form = pq ('<form />')
          ->attr (array (
                    'id' => 'signup_form',
                    'action' => 'registration/signup.php',
                    'method' => 'POST',
                  ));
$label = pq ('<label />')
          ->html ('Name')
          ->attr ('for', 'fname')
          ->appendTo ($form);
$text = pq ('<input />')
          ->attr (array (
                    'name' => 'fname',
                    'data-placeholder' => 'Please enter your name',
                    'type' => 'text',
                  ))
          ->addClass ('valid')
          ->appendTo ($label);
```

I've written it with the formatting I prefer, and it's slightly more lines than in the code you've supplied; but it could easily be reduced to 5-10 or so lines with maintained readability, if you prefer more compact coding. At any rate, I find it quite a lot easier to read and you don't have to write quite so much `DOM` code in order to generate quite a lot of HTML code.

Also, given that `phpQuery` uses the same wrapping concept as `jQuery`, an unwrapped node, for instance `$form` in the above code, is a regular `DOMNode` unless wrapped in `pq()`. This gives you a lot of flexibility to either use `phpQuery`'s convenience routines, or the more "fundamental" functionality of `PHP DOM`.